# How to use QT 4.8.x for VS 2013?

Tags: c++, qt

Now My window version is WIN 8.1. My job work on VS 2013. And now i want to use QT 4.8.3 for it. I used to build QT 4.8.3 through command prompt. It's success. I have some question?

- Which Qt add-in version do I use? On QT have 2 version : 1.11 and 1.24. I install only with 1.24 (for QT5)
- I build a project use QT design on VS2013. When it build my resource project, it show error : compile is out of heap space. I add "/ZM1000" in command line (project properties). But not success.
- Who can show me use QT 4.8.3 for VS2013?
  Thanks!

Comment: I use it without the addon but use CMake to generate my visual studio project files. CMake has support for Qt so it generates the build steps required to run moc, qic.. Also I modified the Qt5 debug natvis to work with Qt4 on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: ***When it build my resource project, it show error : compile is out of heap space. I add "/ZM1000" in command line (project properties). But not success.*** I have never had that issue however I am using CMake to generate the project files.

Comment: @drescherjm: Can you help me? I don't know Cmake to generate my visual studio project files?

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Qt

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. I know reason. I remove qrc_xxx.cpp in solution explorer. Rebuild and success

Answer (score 1):

I remove qrc_xxx.cpp in solution explorer. Rebuild and success